# How to find the injected hook dll?

Tags: .net, hook, pinvoke

I'm implementing a `.NET` application.

It sets a global hook `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` with `P/Invoke` to `SetWindowsHookEx`.

The hook callback procedure resides in an isolated dll `hook.dll`.

When I start another `.NET` appliction `Victim.exe`, the key strike is successfully hooked.

As I know, this `hook.dll` should invade into other process space with any key strike.

But I did NOT find it in `Victim.exe` processes' loaded modules or current app domain referenced assemblies.

Is there any way to indicate if the `hook.dll` is injected? Or is it completely wrong?

Comment: @Metalskin awesome edit

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Low level keyboard hooks are not injected into all processes. The keyboard hook is executed in the context of the thread and process that installed it.

Check out the Remarks section of the [LowLevelKeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.